# Sum of combination of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find a general formula that will find the sum of all the combinations of a list of numbers multiplied together. I want this formula to be restricted to only a specific amount of numbers in each combination. **Repetition is not allowed. Order is not important (237 is the same as 732).**

For example: Find a general formula for the sum of all three digit combinations of the following list of numbers: {2, 3, 7, 8, 10}

Exhaustive method:
(2)(3)(7) +
(2)(3)(8) +
(2)(3)(10) +
(2)(7)(8) +
(2)(7)(10) +
(2)(8)(10) +
(3)(7)(8) +
(3)(7)(10) +
(3)(8)(10) +
(7)(8)(10)

I know how to find the number of combinations (using combinatorics). I want to do further analysis where I use the known amount of combinations to find the sum (given the original list of numbers). Ask if further clarification is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to say $e_3=\frac 16(p_1^3-3p_1p_2+2p_3)$  Here $e_3$ is the third elementary symmetric polynomial, which is what you asked about.  $p_i$ is the sum of the $i^{\text{th}}$ powers of the numbers in your set.  For five numbers and subsets of three it is not much less work than just computing them.  If your set were larger it would win out.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple formula, but this has a name. It's the third elementary symmetric polynomial in five variables. See [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)